# What is the type returned by quandl.get?

Tags: python, quandl

I'm currently following tutorial in which you get data form quandl. I know the basics of python, but I can't figure out what is the type returned by quandl.get. I have searched for it, but everything I found refers to pandas. Do you know what type is it and where can I read some documentation about it?
Here is the code I don't undestand:

```
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]
```

I also dont get why there are double brackets in the second line, but I hope it will be clear after I can read something about it.

Comment: Have you tried `type(df)` after the call to `quandl.get()`?

Comment: Or `print(type(df))`.

Comment: Thanks,I didn't know you can do that. It returned `class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'` . So i guess it the default type returned by quandl.get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Quandl's [documentation](https://www.quandl.com/docs/api#get-data), it is by default a pandas data frame, and you can set `returns = "numpy"` to get a numpy object as an alternative.

```
Definition:
quandl.get(":database_code/:dataset_code", returns = ":return_format")

Parameters:
The parameter returns can take the following values:

   "numpy" : returns a numpy object
   "pandas" : returns a pandas data frame
When returns is omitted, a pandas dataframe is returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

The two sets of square brackets mean the dataframe is a 2 dimensional array ie lots of colums- inner bracket and one row-outer bracket. This reffers to the title row of the dataframe.